# How to use cookies in Electron + Angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript, cookies, electron

I created an Electron with Angular app based on this [template](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron) (Angular 8.2, Electron 7.0).

So far, I'm using [ngx-cookie-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service). 
I just want to store a few settings local, e.g. the last open view and so on.

When I'm building the app as website, the cookies are working fine. 
When I'm building the app as electron app, the cookies are not working.

I tried the Electron cookies [example](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/cookies), but couldn't get it running.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?